# X-ray Diffraction Lattice Spacing

Tags: materials, x-ray-diffraction, lattices

I have crystal structure data which I have indexed.  I am able to index the (010) (100) (011) (110) and (111) planes.  Is there a straightforward method to calculate the a,b,c lattice constants based on this data or is this analysis more complex.  The space group of the material is P2/c.

I understand that I will likely need to use Bragg's Law, but I am unsure exactly how this relates to the lattice constant.

Comment: You'll need the expression for $d_{hkl}$.